# DOM manipulation of elements outside of a react component

Tags: reactjs, dom-manipulation

I've made a dismissible sidebar in react but inside the sidebar component i and making a document call to classes that aren't inside the component. I wanted to know if its an ok coding practice to do document calls to classes that are outside of a component. If it isn't what would be a better alternative?

```
  if (this.state.sideBarOpen === false) {
    for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('u-session-width').length; i++) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('u-session-width')[i].style.width = 'calc(100vw - 59rem)';
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('u-session-width').length; i++) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('u-session-width')[i].style.width = '98%';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use React to render the rest of the page, I'm not aware of any cleaner API for doing what you need.

I would suggest separating those side effects from the component itself though: for example you could add two callback props called `onHide` and `onShow` that get called when the component's state changes, and then shove the code that manipulates the DOM inside those.

```
if (this.state.sideBarOpen === false) {
  this.props.onHide();
} else {
  this.props.onShow();
}
```

And where you render the component:

```
const setSessionWidth = (width) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('u-session-width').length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('u-session-width')[i].style.width = width;
  }
};

<Sidebar
  ...
  onShow={() => setSessionWidth('calc(100vw - 59rem)')}
  onHide={() => setSessionWidth('98%')}
/>
```